# Force 4g over Wifi to make Api Calls

Tags: android, api, flutter, iot

i'm making and IOT app with Flutter, and i have to connecto to an API. There's a way to force the app to use 4g (or any kind of phone network), instead wifi to make these calls?, any kind of library or so?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that should be avoided in a production app due to cellular and data fees.  Also, there is **no** system in place to choose between your phone's available connections when making network requests.